# How to walk through elements of a tree with a Haskell monadic function?

Tags: haskell, tree, monads

I've defined a new data type representing a tree. I've also implemented a function `walk` to walk over all elements of the tree, the functional version of the function is correct but not his monadic version `walkM`.

```
module Hdot where
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import qualified Data.Map as Map

data RDoll a = Null | RDoll a [RDoll a] deriving (Show)    

test :: RDoll Int
test = RDoll 1 [RDoll 2 [Null], RDoll 3 [RDoll 4 [Null]]]

walk :: (a -> b) -> RDoll a -> [b]

walk f Null          = []
walk f (RDoll x rds) = ((f x): (concatMap (\x -> walk f x) rds))

walkM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> RDoll a -> m [b]
walkM f Null            = return []
walkM f (RDoll rd rdss) = do
  x <- f rd
  xs <- concatMap (walkM f) rdss
  return (x:xs)
```

There is a type error

```
Couldn't match type `b' with `[b]'
...
```

Can somebody help me !

thanks for any reply.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, you should give the full error message, since it has valuable context:

```
A.hs:19:26:
    Could not deduce (m ~ [])
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the type signature for
                 walkM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> RDoll a -> m [b]
      at A.hs:(16,1)-(20,15)
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            walkM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> RDoll a -> m [b]
          at A.hs:16:1
    Expected type: [b]
      Actual type: m b
    Expected type: a -> [b]
      Actual type: a -> m b
    In the first argument of `walkM', namely `f'
    In the first argument of `concatMap', namely `(walkM f)'
```

So there's some confusion between lists of values `[b]` and actions `m b`.

The suspicious code is your use of concatMap to run `walkM` recursively. I think you mean to use `concatMapM` (e.g. `mapM` and `concat`):

```
walkM :: (Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> RDoll a -> m [b]
walkM f Null            = return []
walkM f (RDoll rd rdss) = do
  x  <- f rd
  xs <- mapM (walkM f) rdss
  return (x:concat xs)
```

---

As a note on style, I'd try to write things a bit differently. Take a look at the [rose tree in the base library](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Tree.html#Tree). In particular, don't define `walk` and `walkM`, define instances for Functor, Monad and reuse existing library functions.

Comment: Thanks you again, That's really helpfull for what I've to do on does `RDolld`.